# How to get value from multiple select option in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want get all selected from me result,for using in my  controller.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="att in arr track by $index"  ng-hide="check">
   <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="phone">{{att.name}}</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="user.charactValue" multiple="true">
            <option ng-repeat="itemss in att.value track by $index" value="{{itemss}}" >{{itemss}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="text-center"><a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewCharacteristic" ng-click="getObj(att)">Добави</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" ng-click="companyBusinessAsset">

$scope.companyBusinessAsset = function() {
    console.log ($scope.charactValue);
    // this return Undefined
};
```

Down  code is using, but each time they enter into if.

```
$scope.charactValue = [];

$scope.$watch ('selected', function(nowSelected) {
    $scope.selectedValues = [];
    console.log(nowSelected)
    // this return Undefined
    console.log('dddd')
    if (!nowSelected) {
        console.log("IFFFFFF");
        return;
    }
    angular.forEach ($scope.charactValue, function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        $scope.charactValue.push (val.id.toString());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in one of my projects as below, hope this helps:

```
 <select multiple="multiple" name="selectedRoleId" ng-model="user.selectedRole" class="form-control">
      <option ng:repeat="role in roleList" value="{{role.Name}}">{{role.Name}}</option>
 </select>
```

then in the submit function in the controller:

```
//declare $scope.user to avoid undefined/notfound error
$scope.user = {}; //above the function
//and inside the function
$scope.submitForm=function() {
    var reguser = new models.register($scope.user);
};
```

you will get the multiple selected values in `$scope.user`'s `selectedRole` property

Comment: This  code work, but i  have  3 multiple select option , in ng-repeat each select have same ng-model.I  get result only on one multiple select option.

Comment: then check your id's/ng-models of the select elements using firebug/developer explorer in the browser. they should be unique of each other

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `ng-multiple="true"` to your `select`.

Comment: I  adding ng-multiple="true", but my  option became in standart option

Comment: @СтилиянГеоргиев Please have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/TXPJZ/1607/

Comment: This  work only if print result in html, but i  do not get  velue in my  controller ( undefined ).

Comment: @СтилиянГеоргиев Works for me. See this updated fiddle with an change-event: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/TXPJZ/1608/